# "Error: Cannot copy a socket file" when using expo + eas build to publish react native to App Store

Tags: react-native, expo

I try to publish my app to App Store by using eas cli: `eas build --platform ios` . After I login using my Apple account, it run about 2 minute and show "Error: Cannot copy a socket file: /Users/tienminhnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/GPUToolsAgent.sock".
My app use expo-ads-admob and react-native-webview. It run fine in Expo Go app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "sudo" in the CLI when running your command? I was getting this error until I removed "sudo". Hope it helps you.